# SQL statements Error in java code using Intellij and DB Navigator

Tags: java, mysql, sql, intellij-idea, jdbc

I am using mysql in intellij IDE? I have DB Navigator installed and tested my connection successfully. I have used mysql workbench to successfully create a database  and am able to see the database(filecatalog) on IDE as shown in the image below

However, when I write SQL statements in my code it gets highlighted(underlined in red) as an error and intellisense says "Unrecognized statement" . Same case for both CREATE table and INSERT statements as shown in the image. Any ideas what I could be missing?
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Eventually I have solved it. The problem wasn't with my code but rather with the version of IDE that I was using (**Community** Version), it wasn't working well with the ***DB Navigator plugin*** that I downloaded,at least for my case.

So I downloaded Intellij **Ultimate** version which includes ***Database Tools and SQL*** support, configured as shown below and the errors disappeared. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the update. I had this same issue and am using the Community Edition. Since I can't afford to get the Ultimate right now, the good thing is even if it shows this error, the code still works. Just writing this here so if someone else finds it, they'd know. ^_^