# Getting unrecognized statement when trying to create a table for SQLite db

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

I am trying to create a table with SQL in java but I get unrecognized statement.

I have looked up many tutorials and even copied the code but I still get the same error.

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE Player "
                + "( "
                + "ID INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                + "Username TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + "isActive INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                + " PRIMARY KEY(ID)"
                + " );";
PreparedStatement ps = this.connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.execute();
```

I expect no errors even to the code that I copied that supposed to work but got the error message is just "Unrecognized statement".

I'm am using the latest version of JDBC for SQLite

**EDIT:** 
Okay so I have built the project and when executed it actually creates the table so why does IntelliJ idea says its an unrecognized statement?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. I copied and pasted your code exactly and it worked fine for me with Xerial's `sqlite-jdbc-3.27.2.1.jar`.

Comment: How is the Connection established?

Comment: Hey i'm so using ```Xerial's sqlite-jdbc-3.27.2.1``` I have created another project with the same jdbc set up I did and it's still didn't work I copied another SQL statement that worked for me in the sql string and I didn't get any issues. it seems to me that every other statements works without any issue but creating a table just doesn't work for no reason.

Comment: I have changed the SDK version just in case from 10 to 12 but still got the issue.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47599377/sql-statements-error-in-java-code-using-intellij-and-db-navigator

Comment: oh wow that was actually the issue thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay the issue wasn't caused by my code but rather the plugin called DB Navigator so I uninstalled it and it got back to normal.